# How do you derive the new mean and variance when two gaussian functions are multiplied together?

Tags: gaussian, probability-distribution-function

I'm trying to understand the contents of this [web-page](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Product_Two_Gaussian_PDFs.html) which suggest that multiplying two Gaussian functions together produce a new Gaussian function with a new mean and variance.

Say I have the two following Gaussian functions:

[image]

The web-page state that the new mean and variance to be:

[image]

I start by multiplying the two functions, but I am unable to get the result into Gaussian form such that I can extract the new mean and variance. Any tips on how these values were calculated?

Comment: wait, are these deterministic Gaussian *functions*, or are they the *probability density functions* of two Gaussian variables? If the latter, you can't just multiply the PDFs...

Comment: Hi: you need to be careful because there was some confusion earlier regarding a similar question ( that I caused ). Are you A) trying to find the distribution of the product of two normally distrbuted rv's. Or are you  B) generating two iid normal rv's, multiplying them to get a product and and want to find the distribution of this product. This link gives the answer for case  A) .https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian